# present participle and infinitive

Tags: infinitives, participles

I came across a question in an ACT English test:

> Their later clocks reflects the Bilys' keen interest in U.S.history, the most notable example____ the American Pioneer History Clock.

I wonder why the only correct one filling the blank must be "being”， not "to be, " since both of them can act as non-predicative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Being" works, not "to be", because you need an absolute construction for the sentence to work and be grammatical. To have an absolute construction you need a non-finite clause with a non-finite verb, or non-predicative as you call it, but **not all non-finite clauses  are absolute constructions**. Yes, "being" and "to be" are both non-finite options but for the clause to qualify as an absolute construction you need a participle. Here, "being" is the present participle of the copula "be" and with "being" you have an absolute construction.

Comment: ♦ Based on what I've learned, I think an absolute construction used sort of like an adverbial phrase or clause to modify the main clause, but here I am not able to tell what type of adverbial construction it functions here. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @CharlieWang Please check out these two very good answers: [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78868/two-absolute-constructions-with-same-meaning) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105900/understanding-absolute-construction)